# "Open" map with typed values

Tags: typescript, types, symbols

I want to define a type of map that is "open" for extension via creating lookup keys that then can be used to lookup the state map. Something like the following code, but not limited to just `string` and `number` as value types:

```js
// Map and lookup key types
export type LookupKey<T> = symbol & { value: T };
export type State = {
  [key: LookupKey<string>]: (typeof key)["value"] | undefined;
  [key: LookupKey<number>]: (typeof key)["value"] | undefined;
}

// Clients can define their "lookup keys"
export const stringSymbol = Symbol('string') as LookupKey<string>;
export const numberSymbol = Symbol('number') as LookupKey<number>;

// ...and then use in a type-safe manner (sort of)
export function whatever(state: State) {
  // fine
  const stringValue: string | undefined = state[stringSymbol];
  state[stringSymbol] = "hello";
  // not fine -- types mismatch!
  const notAStringValue: number | undefined = state[stringSymbol];
  state[stringSymbol] = 123; 
}
```

Is it possible to write such a type signature in TypeScript? I want `State` to be a concrete type, in other words, it should not have type parameters.

Comment: "I want `State` to be a concrete type, in other words, it should not have type parameters." Then the answer is just "no", unfortunately; why can't you use a generic?

Comment: I don't want to use generics because they proliferate and infect everything around them (well, tbh, this is my experience from other type-safe language). I want this "openness" where you have this "state" and you can pass any kind of information in it.
I was kind of hoping for some higher-typeness like "for each type V if key is LookupKey<V>", then property type is V".

Comment: TypeScript lacks "generic values" of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  So there's no object type like `<V>Record<LookupKey<V>,V | undefined>`.  Only function types can be made generic that way (e.g., `{ set<V>(key: LookupKey<V>, val: V): void; get<V>(key: LookupKey<V>): V | undefined }`).  I can write up an answer saying as much, but the short answer is still "no".